# Map based application not working in KitKat devicesv

Tags: android, google-maps

My map appication (to show nearby places like Hospitals, Restaurants, etc) works in ICS, Lollipop & Marshmallow. In Jellybean and KitKat, a blank map appears. It is showing the world map with just the current location and no nearby place is loaded. On debugging, the latitude & longiude values which I am getting are (0,0).
Its working perfectly in devices other than KitKat & Jellybean.
Does anyone has any idea about the possible loction issue & solution for the same?

Comment: Since your code works on other Android versions (probably higher), this may be a matter of backward compatibility. Kindly check my post about [backward compatibility in android maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476987/how-to-implement-google-maps-with-best-possible-backward-compatibility-in-an-and) and this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922518/android-maps-api-v2-backward-compatibility) which tackles the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add it inside your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```